# Fresh Magento 2.1.14, Readiness Check fail with conflicting component dependencies

Tags: magento2, dependency, component

My Magento is 2.1.14, fresh new. I am trying to install my first extension (Stripe payment extension), and this error occur.

===========================================
Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

For additional assistance, see component dependency help .

===========================================

As it doesn't show any useful information, I just want to know if anyone can help find the problem?

[Information of your environment]
My php version is 5.6.37
Cron scripts are:

/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini /home/kuohua/www/online-store/bin/magento cron:run > home/kuohua/www/online-store/var/log/magento.cron.log
/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini /home/kuohua/www/online-store/update/cron.php > /home/kuohua/www/online-store/var/log/update.cron.log
/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini /home/kuohua/www/online-store/bin/magento setup:cron:run > /home/kuohua/www/online-store/var/log/setup.cron.log

Answer (score 0):

Please use PHP min version 7.0 to avoid readiness issue.

Comment: The php version check will not pass if I change the php version

Comment: What is the PHP version you used for Magento2 Application.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6

Comment: Please use min PHP ver 7.0. You can see below Magento documentation:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html